# Strong variations in runtime statistics when profiling program with ghc RTS

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

I'm trying to profile my program. I compiled it with

```
stack build --executable-profiling --library-profiling --ghc-options=" -fprof-auto -rtsopts=all -caf-all"
```

When running the program there are strong variations within the runtime statistics:

```
./example +RTS -s -sstderr

      68,183,336 bytes allocated in the heap
       7,520,984 bytes copied during GC
         573,296 bytes maximum residency (5 sample(s))
          34,728 bytes maximum slop
               3 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                 Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       127 colls,     0 par    0.020s   0.007s     0.0001s    0.0004s
  Gen  1         5 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.002s     0.0005s    0.0007s

  TASKS: 4 (1 bound, 3 peak workers (3 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.012s  (  0.026s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.020s  (  0.010s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  PROF    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.032s  (  0.038s elapsed)

Alloc rate    5,681,944,666 bytes per MUT second

Productivity  37.5% of total user, 31.8% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 0
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 0
gen[1].sync: 0
```

And the next run gives:

```
$ ./example +RTS -s -sstderr

     68,183,336 bytes allocated in the heap
      7,520,984 bytes copied during GC
        573,296 bytes maximum residency (5 sample(s))
         34,728 bytes maximum slop
              3 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                 Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       127 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.007s     0.0001s    0.0002s
  Gen  1         5 colls,     0 par    0.004s   0.002s     0.0004s    0.0006s

  TASKS: 4 (1 bound, 3 peak workers (3 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.024s  (  0.025s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.004s  (  0.009s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  PROF    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.028s  (  0.036s elapsed)

Alloc rate    2,840,972,333 bytes per MUT second

Productivity  85.7% of total user, 67.5% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 0
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 0
gen[1].sync: 0
```

The program was invoked in the exact same way (without being recompiled of course); yet the `Productivity` changes from 38% to over 85% and other values are totally different, too. <s>Furthermore the fields `GC time` and `total memory use` are missing</s> ... what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: "Furthermore the fields GC time and total memory use are missing" No they aren't

Comment: Maybe it's just a matter of e.g. whether GC happened to happen once or twice? Is your program running for a very brief period?

Comment: @jberryman Yes, it's only running for a very short time ... why is garbage collection not deterministic in that case?

Comment: It may not be the garbage collection that is non-deterministic, but the profiling. All the allocation numbers are precisely identical for both runs (for which the profiler presumably has exact statistics) but I've never seen identical times from two differents runs of a program in the profiler. ["Disabling the interval timer is useful for debugging, because it eliminates a source of non-determinism at runtime."](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html#rts-options-misc)